# IMAP - OTP unavailable error

Tags: python, email, imap

I am trying to get emails from a remote mail server with a python script with the help of the imaplib modules IMAP4 class. It seems to work most of the time, but sometimes I get errors like this:

```
command: CAPABILITY => unexpected response: '<35>Jul 17 09:20:02 imapd[13047]: OTP unavailable because can't read/write key database /etc/opiekeys: Permission denied* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 ACL QUOTA LITERAL+ MAILBOX-REFERRALS NAMESPACE UIDPLUS ID NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND SORT THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES IDLE STARTTLS AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=CRAM-MD5 AUTH=DIGEST-MD5 X-NETSCAPE'
```

Could someone tell me what these messages mean, what is the cause of this, and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your server has a bug and/or is misconfigured.  It looks like it's printing a log line into the command stream.  It appears to be stuck to the beginning of the actual response.